# is there a package for multi-start optimization written in python?

Tags: python, optimization

folks,

I am wondering if such a package exists? Or is there a good reference for implementing it?

Comment: If you google for 'multi start optimization python' you get several links that seem useful, provided you have the domain specific knowlegde to evaluate them.

Answer (score 0):

scipy ,  pyANN , and pyevolve are some packages that come to mind that may have some tools to help with this... Im not entirely sure what multistart optimization is but I have a rough idea ...